# How to have a JavaScript file go off when a text box is unfocused?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I am looking for a way to have my JavaScript file go off when the user un-focuses on a text box on my site.

Background Info:

This is for a Sign Up form that checks to see if the users "Password" and "Confirm Password" fields match. The script I have written so far turns both of the text box's borders red when the user tries to submit the signup data, but the passwords don't match.

What I want to happen:

I instead of the text box's borders turning red when the passwords don't match after the user tries to submit the form, I would like to have this Script fire off when the user un-focuses on the "Confirm Password" text box, and the passwords don't match.

My Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="FormInput3">

    <h3>Create Password</h3>

    <input id="pass1" class="signup-textboxes" placeholder="Enter your desired password..." type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100">

</div>

<div id="FormInput4">

    <h3>Confirm Password</h3>

    <input id="pass2" class="signup-textboxes" placeholder="Confirm your password..." type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100">

</div>

<button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
```

CSS:

```
/* ****Password 1**** */

#signupform > #FormInput3 {

    width: 450px;

    height: 40px;

    line-height: 40px;

    margin-left: 20px;

    display: block;

    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

}

#signupform > #FormInput3 h3 {

    vertical-align: middle;

    font-family: "Lato Light", Arial;

    color: gray;

    font-size: 20px;

    font-family: "Lato Regular", Arial;

    font-weight: 100;

    margin-left: 24px;

}

#signupform > #FormInput3 > #pass1{

    float: right;

    color: gray;

    margin-top: -60px;

    width: 250px;

    background-color: #000;

    border: none;

    height: 30px;

    margin-right: 5px;

    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;

    font-size: 15px;

    outline: none;

    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

    -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

    -ms-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

    transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

}

#signupform > #FormInput3 > #pass1:hover {

    border-color: #fff;

    color: white;

}

#signupform > #FormInput3 > #pass1:focus{

    border-color: #fff;

    color: white;

}

/* ****Password 2**** */

#signupform > #FormInput4 {

    width: 450px;

    height: 40px;

    line-height: 40px;

    margin-left: 20px;

    display: block;

    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

}

#signupform > #FormInput4 h3 {

    vertical-align: middle;

    font-family: "Lato Light", Arial;

    color: gray;

    font-size: 20px;

    font-family: "Lato Regular", Arial;

    font-weight: 100;

    margin-left: 10px;

}

#signupform > #FormInput4 > #pass2 {

    float: right;

    color: gray;

    margin-top: -60px;

    width: 250px;

    background-color: #000;

    border: none;

    height: 30px;

    margin-right: 5px;

    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;

    font-size: 15px;

    outline: none;

    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

    -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

    -ms-transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

    transition: border-color 0.3s ease;

}

#signupform > #FormInput4 > #pass2:hover {

    border-color: #fff;

    color: white;

}

#signupform > #FormInput4 > #pass2:focus{

    border-color: #fff;

    color: white;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
function signup(){
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
if(p1 != p2){

     status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match.";

     document.getElementById("pass1").style.borderColor="red";

     document.getElementById("pass1").style.color="red";

     document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="red";

     document.getElementById("pass2").style.color="red";
 }
}
```

Like I mentioned before, the JavaScript file you see here does what I want, but only after the user clicks the "Sign Up" Button. Please let me know if it is possible to do what I am asking. Thanks in advance! (For reference, please go to http://www.codesrce.com/signup.php)

Comment: Use the `blur` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), but in plain js and html you can use the onblur event

```
<input id="pass2" class="signup-textboxes" placeholder="Confirm your password..." type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onblur="signup()" maxlength="100">
```

Comment: Okay I will give that a try. If it doesn't work, I might just resort to using jQuery.

Comment: Why would you recommend jQuery for something that simple that javascript can already do?

Comment: Because he is probably trying to help me modernize my site. But not to worry, that worked like a charm. I appreciate the help. I will accept this answer when I can.

Comment: @Shryme Because it's possible that there is a lot more to the app than a plain sign up page, and using jQuery would make things a lot easier if you add it right from the start rather than trying to convert everything at a later stage

Comment: Please check out my site and see that it worked. Try entering passwords that don't match, and then make them match and see that the red goes back to gray. Thank you very much. http://www.codesrce.com/signup.php

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of focus is blur..

https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Ouch. Then.. I await for an answer.